# Problem in submitting my code to CodeWars due to decimal places

Tags: c

I am practicing C on code wars and there is this problem where i have to calculate the area of a regular n sides polygon inside a circle of radius r .

I have written the formula correctly but when i test , i am unable to submit my code.Here is my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double PI = 3.141592653589793; // Use this value as pi in your calculations if necessary

double area_of_polygon_inside_circle(double circle_radius, int number_sides) {
  double result,y;
  
  y = (double) number_sides;
  
  result = ((y/2)*circle_radius*circle_radius)*(sin(2*PI/y));
  
  result = (floor(1000.0*result)/1000);
  
  return result;
}
```

This is the error I am getting.

Expected: 502.526 Received: 502.525000 for area_of_polygon_inside_circle(13, 11)

Comment: Why do you use `floor` and not `round`? Did anything in the requirements ask you to round down? The error message tells you that your result is a bit too low. That might be caused by your rounding decision.